# Excision on (co)homology of the product of CW complexes

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

While reading the proof of the Relative Künneth's Formula on *Hatcher's*, I came across the following isomorphism
$$
H^\ast(X \times y_0 \cup A \times Y, A \times Y) \cong H^\ast(X \times y_0, A \times y_0),
$$
where the pairs $(X,A)$ and $(Y,y_0)$ are CW pairs such that $X$ and $Y$ have finitely many cells in each dimension, and $H^\ast$ is the singular cohomology ring.

From my understanding, this should come from excision, but I don't see why it should hold; to excise $A \times (Y \setminus \{y_0\})$ we should have that
$$
\overline{A \times (Y \setminus \{y_0\})} = \overline{A} \times \overline{(Y \setminus \{y_0\})} = \overline{A} \times Y \subset (A \times Y)^\circ = A^\circ \times Y,
$$

which doesn't hold in general. What am I getting wrong?

The proof can be seen in [Hatcher's book](https://pi.math.cornell.edu/%7Ehatcher/AT/AT+.pdf), at page 219; if needed, I can add it as a picture here. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In its standard form "excision" is described in Theorem 2.20. It works for singular homology **and** cohomology (see p.201).

The problem is that not any $Z \subset A$ can be excised from the pair $(X,A)$; we need some "niceness condition". The standard requirement is that the closure of $Z$ is contained in the interior of $A$.

Unfortunately this is in general not satisfied for $A \times (Y \setminus \{y_0\})$. However, we work with *CW-complexes*, and Hatcher proved that excision also works for *subcomplexes* if we use the equivalent formulation in the second sentence of Theorem 2.20 (see Corollary 2.24).

We can apply this for $\bar X = X \times \{y_0\} \cup A \times Y$ with $\bar A = A \times Y$ and $\bar B = X \times \{y_0\}$.